# ¿Cómo creo en Python una cadena de n caracteres?

Tags: python, string

A veces me ocurre que hago una función determinada que hace alguna cosa con una cadena de caracteres, como por ejemplo reducir su tamaño, convertir a mayúsculas, etc.

Entonces luego voy a crear mis unittests y quiero ofrecer diferentes ejemplos de entrada que sean representativos, pero también legibles. Por ello, escribir una cadena del tipo `s = "hola bla bla blaldadald adf asdlfasfasl"` no me es útil, pero también necesito que sean cadenas largas.

También probé con cosas del tipo:

```
s = ""
for i in range(10):
    s += "hola "
```

Pero me parece algo pesado.

Por ello, ¿hay alguna manera de escribir una cadena muy larga con apenas una línea de código?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1424005/1983854

Comment: Igual te interesa probar [Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Usa `*`!

```
s = "hola " * 10
```

Te devuelve

```
>>> "hola " * 10
'hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola '
```

Si quieres que la cadena se componga de, por ejemplo, muchos caracteres aleatorios, puedes usar:

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase

"".join(choice(ascii_lowercase) for i in range(10))
```

Que te devolverá cosas del tipo `'eopzwojuiq'` o `'wixlzifuig'`.

Answer (score 0):

1. ¿por qué no usar la cadena de 144 palabras que trae Python directamente?
2. salvo que no te sirva que sea en inglés
3. se podría hacer asi:

hay que redirigir la salida del módulo `this` porque sino la imprime directamente no es algo que quiera en este caso

```
import contextlib, io
zen_python = io.StringIO()
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(zen_python):
    import this

texto = zen_python.getvalue().split()
```

con esto obtenemos una lista de palabras, sino usas el `split` obtendrás una cadena

Y ¿Cómo hago para que devuelva una cadena de x palabras?
pues con una función:

```
def cuantas(numero):
    return " ".join(texto[:numero] )
```

Donde unimos a una cadena la cantidad de elementos que quieras

si:

```
cadena = cuantas(10)
print(cadena)
```

obtenemos:

```
>>> The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters Beautiful is better
```

listo, una cadena con sentido(básicamente) de 10 palabras